# output in xlsx file in c++

Tags: c++, xlsx

I need to write output of a c++ project in .xlsx file. such that for if i write

```
  cout<<"value="<<variable_value
```

them it print "value=" and "value of variable" in two column. for this i first use [www.libxl.com/](http://www.libxl.com) but there has many problem(one of this is write banner in first row of each spreadsheet and not able more than 100 cells )

in one question of this site i got this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx

it  for webpage.can I use this in my c++ project? how?

if i can't, anyone know another solution?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem some time ago. Since a haven`t found existing libraries meeting  my demands I`ve written a small API for writing .xlsx files myself.
Here the link to the project: [SimpleXlsx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexlsx/)

It provides no dependencies from OLE or other specifics. May be it will worth to try